# Is it possible to remove thumbnail borders in nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I have just installed Gnome on my PC and all picture thumbnails (both on desktop and in Nautilus) have ugly white borders. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: Probably not easily doable, you might have to recompile nautilus: https://answers.launchpad.net/cover-thumbnailer/+question/186685. Also see this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360415/how-to-remove-the-thumbnail-frame-in-nautilus